# python - split beautifulsoup object using reg expressions

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am having trouble finding a solution to split the time period and the route that are contained in a 'div' that i have scraped using beautifulsoup.  Below is the text I get from the interactive shell.  I need to split 'via I-405/I-65/I-525' and '8 min. 46 sec.'  Then I need to get rid of 'min' and 'sec' so I can combine to get '8.46'.  I am guessing I need to use split with regular expressions?  Can someone give me an example of such?  Thanks.

Here is what I scraped off the webpage:

```
<div class="coloredodd" id="odContent">
    <b>via I-405/I-65/I-525</b>
    <br></br>
    58 min. 8 sec.
    <br></br>
</div>
```

Here is what I get running from the shell:

```
>>> soup.find_all('div')[16].get_text()

'via I-405/I-65/I-5258 min. 46 sec.'
```

Here is what I am trying to do with the dictionaries:

```
LinkNames[1] = TempLinkNames[7]
LinkNames[2] = TempLinkNames[8]
LinkNames[3] = TempLinkNames[9]
LinkNames[4] = TempLinkNames[4]
LinkNames[5] = TempLinkNames[2]
LinkNames[6] = TempLinkNames[5]
LinkNames[7] = TempLinkNames[3]
LinkNames[8] = TempLinkNames[0]
LinkNames[9] = TempLinkNames[1]
print(LinkNames)
```

Here is the first item of the dictionary:

```
{'At BTI Road via Ocean Expy (I-525)': '32.48',
```

Here is how I went around it putting the key and values into lists first then manually assigning it to a dictionary.

```
BWPLinkNames = {BWPCombineNames[6]: BWPSingLinkTime[6],
                BWPCombineNames[7]: BWPSingLinkTime[7],
                BWPCombineNames[8]: BWPSingLinkTime[8],
                BWPCombineNames[9]: BWPSingLinkTime[9],
                BWPCombineNames[4]: BWPSingLinkTime[4],
                BWPCombineNames[2]: BWPSingLinkTime[2],
                BWPCombineNames[5]: BWPSingLinkTime[5],
                BWPCombineNames[3]: BWPSingLinkTime[3],
                BWPCombineNames[0]: BWPSingLinkTime[0],
                BWPCombineNames[1]: BWPSingLinkTime[1]}
```

Having trouble outputting dictionary item to spreadsheet.  The value are float strings '23.25'.  But on the spreadsheet it is showing up incorrectly with error.  It only shows up as one digit number, and the number has nothing to do with the actual float string.  Using the xlsxwriter for excel and here is how I am outputting them.

```
for key in BWLinkNames.keys():

    worksheet.write(row, col, key)
    for value in BWLinkNames[key]:
        worksheet.write(row, col + 1, value)
    row+= 1
workbook.close()
```

Comment: This isn't a BeautifulSoup problem necessarily since you can use any string parsing methods you want once you have the text. That said, it looks like something may be missing since there doesn't appear to be a divider between the direction  (via I-405/I-65/I-525) and the time (8 min. 46 sec.). What is soup.find_all('div')[16]?

Comment: @EliotK I edited my initial question. Hope this clears it up.  In the webpage, there are many destination routes and its respective travel times.  The expression soup.find_all('div')[16] just brings up one of them.

Comment: Thought so. That HTML provides you with the separators you need to be accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
s = 'via I-405/I-65/I-5258 min. 46 sec.'
[timestamp] = re.findall('\d{1}\smin\.\s\d+\ssec', s)
final_result = '.'.join(re.findall('\d+', timestamp))
```

Output:

```
'8.46'
```

Edit: you can use `BeautifulSoup` to find the destination, and then use `str.replace`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import re
s = """
<div class="coloredodd" id="odContent">
  <b>via I-405/I-65/I-525</b>
  <br></br>
  58 min. 8 sec.
  <br></br>
</div>
"""
destination = soup(s, 'html.parser').find('b').text
timestamp = '.'.join(re.findall('\d+', soup(s, 'html.parser').find('div').text.replace(destination, '')))
```

Output:

```
'via I-405/I-65/I-525'
'58.8'
```

Edit: instead of iterating over `BWLinkNames[key]`, simple utilize `BWLinkNames[key]`:

```
for i, key in enumerate(BWLinkNames):
  worksheet.write(i, col, key)
  worksheet.write(i, col + 1, BWLinkNames[key])

workbook.close()
```

Comment: Just a caveat to this solution: This works only if the minute is one digit.

Comment: @EliotK That is true. The OP will need to clarify, although I think that particular problem can be resolved by being more precise in the scraping of the webpage to begin with, rather than relying on additional parsing after the fact.

Comment: @Ajax1234 Thanks that worked.  Now if I had to do many of these within a given webpage, I would then have to store each scraped element that contains the combine destination and time, in a list, and take each out one at a time to separate them?  The end goal is to have two columns (dest, time) in a spreadsheet.  Would I have to put the two back into a list separately, before I manipulate them to put it in a spreadsheet?

Comment: @superx That can be done, however, what separates dest and time? For instance, is `I-405/I-65/I-52518 min. 46 sec.` `I-405/I-65/I-5251`, `8 min. 46 sec.`, or  `I-405/I-65/I-525`, `18 min. 46 sec`?

Comment: @Ajax1234 I edited my Question up top where it includes the section that I scrapped from the webpage.  And below that when I do a find_all on the 'div' I get as one "I-405/I-65/I-52518 min. 46 sec."    Is there anyway to scrapped the dest and time separately other then what I did?  And if you can tell me the best sequence to populate the two values in a spreadsheet.  Not sure If i should put the combined scrapped data in a list first, then separate them using reg exp, and put them back in a list separately.  Thanks

Comment: @Ajax1234 Thanks that worked nicely!  I was having a hard time trying to see how it worked so i had to reverse engineer it for me to really understand it.  So i'm guessing all is left to do is to store each destination and timestamp in a list in order to create a spreadsheet listing a column for each value?

Comment: @superx Correct. BTW, are there multiple `div`s with class `coloredodd` on the HTML page? If so, I can add a solution that can handle that, along with writing the results to a `.csv` file.

Comment: @Ajax1234 Yes there many of these elements that are within div's.  I was hoping to go through each index to see where they each are, because some div's do not contain the info I need.  I was also doing this as a learning experience, so can I have a day to work this out before getting back to you for a solution?  Many thanks for leading the way!

Comment: @superx Glad to help!

Comment: @Ajax1234 I came to a stop and need your help.  I added the destination and time into a dictionary.  Key(Destination): Value(time).  I am having a hard time accessing the dictionary with indexing.  I read that indexing cant be done on dictionaries is that true?  Are there any functions that can help me overcome this?  I need to copy items from a temp dictionary into another dictionary.  And the end goal is to print the items from the dictionary to a spreadsheet.  Thanks.

Comment: @superx Dictionaries utilize hashing, which means you can pass it any key that has been originally added to your dictionary. Can you post your dictionary?

Comment: @Ajax1234 I added the dictionary copy that I was attempting in my original question post.  And also the first item of the dictionary.  The items in the temp dictionary needs to be in a certain order.

Comment: @Ajax1234 I have a workaround solution. Please see above.  I added each destination and time into their respective list.  I then manually added the key-value combo into a dictionary manually.  It works for the time being.

Comment: @Ajax1234 Can you help me with an excel outputting error?  I am using xlsxwriter to output the dictionary items.  One column for string destinations, and one column for string time.  But the time is not showing correctly.  It shows up with a single digit number.  I would like to convert the value 'time' to a float, so I can do calculations on it. I have my code above in my original. Thanks

Comment: @superx I have not used `xlsxwriter` before, however, to convert the time value to float, should it not be `float(value)`?

Comment: @Ajax1234 Yes it is.  That is actually my second issue (converting the string to float).  When I did convert it I am getting 'TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable' when using: for value in BWLinkNames[key]:    If I can somehow convert it to float then writing float to excel would eliminate my first problem.  But it isnt allowing me.  Does python allow me to iterate float value from dictionary?

Comment: @Ajax1234 Yes that worked!  You are a genius and you just made my weekend.   I am going to continue this on Monday. Thanks again for leading the way and I hope you enjoy your weekend.

Comment: @superx Glad to help!